# Yii2 - How to set Time in Log messages?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am using `EmailTarget` in Yii2 and I am logging messages like this.

```
Yii::info('Log message example','mail');
```

After successful execution, I am receiving mail like this:

```
2018-07-31 09:01:12 [127.0.0.1][user@example.com][-][info][mail] Log message example
```

By default Yii2 generating log messages and displaying time in GMT format.

How can I configure time in these log messages?

Comment: Log time is formatted using [this method](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.15.1/framework/log/Target.php#L365-L370) so only way to change it is to override it.

Comment: [getTime()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.15.1/framework/log/Target.php#L365-L370) method in `Target` is protected. I think it should be public so that one can configure log messages time.

Comment: @Akshaypjoshi Changing visibility will not magically allow you to configure log message time. `protected` is enough if you want to override this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This log target uses `date()` for date formatting, so if you're getting date with wrong timezone, you probably have incorrect timezone settings in your PHP. You may use [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to change timezone used by `date()`, for example in your config:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

See also [list of available timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

---

If your log target should use different timezone than the rest of the application, you may create custom target and override [`getTime()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-log-target#getTime()-detail) in this way:

```
protected function getTime($timestamp) {
    $oldTimezone = date_default_timezone_get();
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); // <- put your timezone here

    $parts = explode('.', StringHelper::floatToString($timestamp));
    $result = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $parts[0]) . ($this->microtime && isset($parts[1]) ? ('.' . $parts[1]) : '');

    date_default_timezone_set($oldTimezone);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I want timezone to be fetched from Database and according to its value DateTime should be display in a log file.

Comment: It will help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new class that extends from `yii\log\EmailTarget` and overwrite the function `formatMessage()` inherited form `yii\Log\Target`.

[Yii 2 Docs (log\Target)](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-log-target#formatMessage()-detail)
[Github source](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/log/Target.php#L264)

Then use that class in your configurations:

```
'components' => [
    'log' => [
         'targets' => [
             [
                'class' => 'your\namespace\CustomEmailTarget',
                'mailer' => 'mailer',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                'message' => [
                    'from' => ['log@example.com'],
                    'to' => ['developer1@example.com', 'developer2@example.com'],
                    'subject' => 'Log message',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```